# Should I use std::mutex or a wrapper around OS specific mutex?

Tags: c++, operating-system, embedded, mutex

I'm looking to make use of an RAII implementation of a mutex in an embedded application. The simplest solution would be to use std::mutex, but is that recommended? I'm not sure exactly how the implementation works, so would it be better to write my own RAII wrapper around my OS specific mutex/semaphore?

Comment: You would need a very good reason to chose the platform-specific mutex over `std::mutex`. Reasons do exist, but you generally have to go looking for them. I'd start with `std::mutex` and only change course if profiling or other circumstances suggest the alternative.

Answer (score 3):

> The simplest solution would be to use std::mutex, but is that recommended?

While creating a RAII wrapper around the platform specific mutex is pretty straight forward I would recommend using `std::mutex` unless the implementation in the standard library is proven broken or strangely bloated.

You could compare the sizes of the mutexes to see if there's anything extra added on top of the platform specific mutex.

[Demo for POSIX mutexes](https://godbolt.org/z/3qhcns34M) where `pthread_mutex_t` and `std::mutex` have the same size.

Comment: 9 out of 10 dentists agree. And the tenth dentist... Well... Uhm...